# Searching huge object by property performant caching

Tags: javascript, filter, react-native, autocomplete

i have a huge js object which hold all user posts,

some users might have more than 300+ post in this object, so i want to implement a search mechanism

example:

```
{
 postById:{
   1:{ id:1, title:'varchar 250 string' },
   2:{ id:2, title:'varchar 250 string' },
   ...etc for 300+ items
 }
}
```

ps.: i' using ES6, its a react-native project.

a simple approach for search can be:

```
_handlSearch(keyword){
  const key= keyword.toLowerCase();
  return Object.keys(postById).filter(id=>posts[id].title.indexOf(key)>-1)
               .map(id=>postById[id])
}
```

now this function is fine, by question is how often should i trigger search ?
and lets say user type "var" this will trigger search, then he add a new letter "varc" so it would make sence to not filter the master object buy rather search the already short list which came from "var".

is there a already existent solution that optimize such autocomplete/search functionality ?

Comment: You can consider debouncing mechanic: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce

Comment: Or throttling: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle

Comment: @lunochkin thanks, but this doesnot fix caching results to avoid searching master when keyword increase a letter.

Comment: You can use debouncing with keyup event handler. Then it will fire actual search request only after user ends typing, may be after 1 letter, may be after 10, depending on how fast user typed it

Comment: @Zalaboza I really like your idea and what you try to achieve. I think that holding map's results while user is searching might do the trick and have a proper logic depending on the searched string. The only problem that i see is when the user types varb and actually wants varc. So the question would be if you should hold the results for "var" and "varb"

Comment: Maybe you could use localStorage to store results and on each new key update it.

Comment: May be you just can maintain cache manually and check if there is occurrences for left substrings? Then you can easily search into the occurrence for the largest left substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated.

You can set master list as `list` state property and then repeatedly search in it until you don't have some keyword which doesn't contain your current keyword in component.

Basically, this version:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ShortList extends Component {

  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {list:props.master,keyword:String(props.keyword||'').toLowerCase()};
      this._hadleSearchMaster = this._hadleSearchMaster.bind(this)
      this.trigger = this.trigger.bind(this)
      this.extract = typeof props.getValue==='function' ? props.getValue : f=>String(f);
      this.minLength = props.minLength||3;
      this.debounce = 0;
  }
  _hadleSearchMaster(){
    const list = Object.keys(this.props.master).map(id=>this.extract(this.props.master[id]).indexOf(this.state.keyword)>-1);
    console.log('searched master and returned'+this.state.keyword,Object.keys(this.props.master),list);
    this.setState({list});
  }
  trigger(){
    clearTimeout(this.debounce);
    this.debounce = setTimeout(this._hadleSearchMaster, 200);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    this.extract = typeof props.getValue==='function' ? props.getValue : f=>String(f);
    if(props.getValue!==this.props.getValue)this.extract = props.getValue;
    if(props.minLength!==this.props.minLength)this.minLength = props.getValue;

    if(!props.keyword || props.keyword.length < this.minLength)return;
    if(props.keyword===this.props.keyword)return;
    
    const keyword = String(props.keyword||'').toLowerCase();
    const stateToSet = {keyword};
    if (keyword.substr(0, this.state.keyword.length) !== this.state.keyword) {
      stateToSet.list = props.master;      
    }
    this.setState(stateToSet,
                  this.trigger)

  }
  render() {
    return this.props.render(this.state.list);
  }
}
//<Shortlist master={{}} style={{}} getValue={f=>f.title.toLowerCase()} keyword='search' render={idList=>null} minLength={3} />
export default ShortList
```